# Questions on independence of increment and increment size in Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory

In Brownian motion the increment $W(t_2)-W(t_1), \; W(t_3)-W(t_2), \; \cdots, \; W(t_n)-W(t_{n-1})$ are independent.

However, I saw that (in proving $\textrm{Cov}\big(W(s),W(t)\big)=\min(s,t), \ \textrm{ for all }s \leq t.$ :

$W(s)=W(s)-W(0)$ and $W(s)-W(t)$ are independent for $s \leq t$.

What my concern is, is that the increments length might be different, i.e. $s-0 \neq s-t$, and from the definition, it seems that only increments (equals in size) are independent. So my question is how can $W(s)-W(t)$ and $W(s)-W(0)$ be independent for any $t \leq s$?

Comment: Where did you see that?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen in proving $\textrm{Cov}\big(W(s),W(t)\big)=\min(s,t), \ \textrm{ for all }t \leq s.$

Comment: It is true that $W(t)-W(0)$ and $W(s)-W(t)$ are independent for $t\le s,$ which is not what you wrote. (And this can be used to compute the covariance.) And no, independent increments has nothing to do with them having the same duration. Just that the time intervals don't overlap. (In what you wrote, they overlap.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I am so sorry, it should be $s \leq t$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen so for any two time increments, as long as they don't overlap, regardless of each increment's size, are independent?

Comment: Yes, so e.g. $W_5-W_4$ and $W_{2000}-W_{1000}$ are independent but $W_{1005} -W_{1004}$ and $W_{2000}- W_{1000}$ aren't independent. This is intuitively because brownian motion is like the sum of a bunch of tiny independent variables (it's a continuum limit of a random walk). So the little variables that contributed to the diff between 1005 and 1004 also contributed to the diff between 2000 and 1000. But the variables that contributed to the diff between 4 and 5 didn't.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I see that now. Thanks for your comment!